# Merging 2 dictionaries having duplicate keys with linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, merge

How to merge 2 dictionaries of `IDictionary<Guid, MyObject>` where `MyObject` is a class instance?

```
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d1 = new Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>();
d1.Add(guid1, m1);
d1.Add(guid2, m2);
d1.Add(guid3, m3);
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d2 = new Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>();
d2.Add(guid2, m2);
d2.Add(guid3, m3);
d2.Add(guid4, m4);
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d3 = d1.Union(d2) ???
```

That in `d3` there are the following entries:

```
guid1,m1
guid2,m2
guid3,m3
guid4,m4
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c

Comment: sorry, I could not find my solutiion there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine two Dictionaries with linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903784/combine-two-dictionaries-with-linq); more exact duplicate than the other one

Comment: Duplicate of [Combine two Dictionaries with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903784/combine-two-dictionaries-with-linq)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
d1.Concat(d2.Where( x=> !d1.Keys.Contains(x.Key)));
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is the correct approach though leading processing of the concatenated set

Comment: @Eric This looks like a good solution. But, if I have `IEnuemrable<Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>>` colection, how can I match items?

Comment: I found union faster when d1 was small (2 records) and d2 was large (100,000 records).

Answer (score 7):

`d1.Union(d2).GroupBy (kvp => kvp.Key).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.First().Value);` out to do the trick.

```
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d1 = new Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>();
d1.Add(guid1, m1);
d1.Add(guid2, m2);
d1.Add(guid3, m3);
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d2 = new Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>();
d2.Add(guid2, m2);
d2.Add(guid3, m3);
d2.Add(guid4, m4);
IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d3 = 
   d1.Union(d2).GroupBy (kvp => kvp.Key)
       .ToDictionary (kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.First ().Value);
```

Comment: thanks but I tried that and Union leads to Exception with 'An item with the same key has already been added'

Comment: I fixed it.  `    IDictionary<Guid, MyObject> d3 = 
       d1.Union(d2).GroupBy (kvp => kvp.Key)
           .ToDictionary (kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.First ().Value);
`

Comment: thank you very much, that works, how that line avoids duplicate keys?
is that faster than `d1.Concat(d2.Where(x => !d1.Keys.Contains(x.Key)))`?

Comment: I tested that using Stopwatch, using of Concat is 3 time faster, SO DO NOT USE Union

Answer (score 4):

If you have duplicate key then you'll have to handle duplicate key with the using of where clause.

```
var result = d1.Union(d2.Where(k => !d1.ContainsKey(k.Key))).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)
```

**Note :** It will not get duplicate key. if there will be any duplicate key than it will get d1's key.

Answer (score 2):

This will merge unique keys and unique list of values:

```
d1.Union(d2).GroupBy(g => g.Key).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.First().Value.Union(pair.Last().Value).ToList());
```

Comment: please explain and format your answer, also is it still relevant after 11years and other answers?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
d1.Concat(d2).Distinct(kv => kv.Key).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)
```

The result of concat makes use of the fact that the dictionary is an `IEnumerable<KeyvaluePair<Guid,MyObject>>`

Since I do not have a compiler I just checked that Distinct cannot accept just a lambda selecting the property to be compared. However it can accept an EqualityComparer. What I often have in projects is a Generic Equality Comparer that allows to pass in lambdas which define the equality operation.

Answer (score 0):

Union looks good:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#union1

Answer (score -1):

When no duplicates keys exist, the following works for 2 (or more) dictionaries:

```
var dictionaries = new [] { d1, d2 };
var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```