# Merging IDictionary - is there a more efficient method than this?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a helper that merges two or more `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` objects into one `IDictionary<TKey, string>` by concatenating the `TValue`'s `ToString()` methods like so:

```
public class DictionaryHelper<TKey, TValue>
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, string> MergeDictionaries<TKey, TValue>(params IDictionary<TKey, TValue>[] dictionaries) where TValue : class
    {
        var returnValue = new Dictionary<TKey, string>();
        foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
            {
                if (returnValue.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
                {
                    returnValue[kvp.Key] += kvp.Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    returnValue[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

While this is straightforward and pretty easy to read, it seems like there should be a more efficient way to do this.  Is there?

Comment: Keep in mind [`kvp.Value` can be `null`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx) Efficient speed or efficient in lines of code?

Comment: Hmm... well, my intended usage shouldn't allow that, but I agree I need to handle that.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Efficient in performance... I don't mind putting a bit more effort in up front.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712927/how-to-add-2-dictionary-contents-without-looping-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if this is more efficient, but at least it's much shorter:

```
var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(d => d)
                         .ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Concat(g));
```

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: if we use yours as a baseline, they're all about even. (*previous version of this comment included deferred dictionary creation in the timing*)

Comment: Interesting.  So the compiler treats them the same, more or less.  Then it becomes all about readability.

Comment: @Jeremy: It meant slower, but I'd included deferred object creation in the timing erroneously. As you increase the size of the dictionary and the number of matches, dtb's takes a *slight* advantage over your code (1.05 speedup).

Answer (score 1):

You could remove a *visible* `foreach` with `SelectMany`:

```
foreach (var kvp in dictionaries.SelectMany(dd => dd))
{
    if (returnValue.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
    {
        returnValue[kvp.Key] += kvp.Value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And you could extend this further, [although dtb's is more elegant and efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398861/7116):

```
var merged = dictionaries.SelectMany(dd => dd)
                         .GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
                         .ToDictionary(
                             gg => gg.Key,
                             gg => String.Concat(gg));
```

However, this is not likely to be more efficient or readable than your current approach.

Comment: You could replace `.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToDictionary(..)` with `.GroupBy(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Concat(g))`. So it's exactly the same as my answer except for GroupBy instead of ToLookup. I wonder which is more efficient...

Comment: Thanks, my gut says that L2O won't see a difference, and ILSpy shows using `GroupBy` in L2O simply defers a call to `Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Create<TSource>()` , which `ToLookup` uses immediately. Not sure there is much of a difference, except mine is making a `Lookup` on the fly and yours already has it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639.aspx) to conflate the location and retrieval of the source value.