# What is the most efficient way to merge dictionaries containing a list

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have introduced the notion of blocks into my system. Each block can be split into sub-blocks.
I thought of a few ways to create or keep track of the sub-blocks within a block and one option could be to have this (any better suggestion is welcome):

```
// // Dictionary <sub-block-number, payload>
Dictionary <UInt16, List<byte>> _payloads { get; set; } = new Dictionary<UInt16, List<byte>>();
```

Now I have no problem adding things to the dictionary, but retrieving the combined payload into a byte[] is causing me problem. I have also seen a bunch of things on stack overflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132562/merging-dictionary-containing-a-list-in-c-sharp)) using Linq, but I am not sure it is the right way to go as some people say it is very inefficient. In all cases, none of these answers return a byte[].
Here is what I would like to implement:

```
// Get combined payload from _payloads dictionary
public byte[] GetTotalPayload()
{ .. }
```

### EDIT

The Lists in the dictionary will be added incrementally one by one from "sub-block-number" = 0 to N.
Not sure if when combining to List it is important to specify that the key has to be ordered incrementally? Probably not.

Comment: It's not clear 1) what the goal with retrieving the byte[] is (if it's writing to a file, writing direct to a file would be more efficient). 2) if there's a specific way in which each entry in the dictionary has to be combined. Can we just take any `List<byte>` for the first item?

Comment: @John, what file? Never mentioned a file. Just how to combine all the lists from the dictionary

Comment: @John, What? I was not being rude. Sorry it came out that way :-) I was editing my question as you were answering. The ordering is a very good point, which does not matter too much, but probably worth taking care of it anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just flatten every list from dictionary value into single one using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) and convert to array

```cs
var payload = _payloads.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();
```

It'll work if the sub-block numbers are really consecutive and sub-blocks itself aren't overlapped. You may also order the items by number `OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)` before flatten the values

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I need :-) Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Using `Enumerable.SelectMany` to flatten the values into a single array.

```
public byte[] GetTotalPayload()
{
    return _payloads.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: That simple! Thanks!