# C# Combine JSON objects

Tags: c#, json

I have multiple instances of JSON objects that have missing or updated information.  I want a way to take all of the JSON objects and combine them into one record in C# (.net 3.5).  If there is an existing field, I want the latest one saved.

for example, if I had all of these objects respectively:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John",
}
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Dow",
    "phone" : "555-555-5555"
}
{
    "id" : 1,
    "phone" : "(555) 555-555"
}
    "id" : 1,
    "position" : "Peon"
}
```

I would want a resulting object equal to:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Dow",
    "phone" : "(555) 555-555"
    "position" : "Peon"
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What happens if there are inconsistencies?  Would that be an exception condition?

Comment: You may want to look at [Does C# have a library for parsing multi-level cascading JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002508/does-c-have-a-library-for-parsing-multi-level-cascading-json), though it's not exactly the same question.

Comment: Inconsistencies should be overwritten by the newest data. I guess I should also say that "id" is the indexable variable. As long as "id" is the same, it should cascade. @Matthew - I'll look into the post!  That looks about like what I want to do :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121010/merge-two-json-net-arrays-by-concatenating-contained-elements)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If doing it in javascript is an option for you prior to c# working with the set then
you could use underscore.js. I don't include any checking to see if id is the same so if this may be the case this needs to be added

```
var objects = [
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John"
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Dow",
    "phone" : "555-555-5555"
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "phone" : "(555) 555-555"
},
{
    "id" : 1,
    "position" : "Peon"
}];

var merged = _.reduce(objects, function(sum, value){ return _.extend(sum, value); }, {});

gives

{
 "id":1,
 "firstName":"John",
 "lastName":"Dow",
 "phone":"(555) 555-555",
 "position":"Peon"
}
```

Comment: I'm not using JS. The second comment in the original thread is the answer that I'm going with.