# Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have two `JToken`'s that represent JSON arrays of objects and I would like to merge them. `JToken` has a method `Concat` but it produces `null` as result when I try to use it.

```
Action<JToken> Ok = (x) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(x);
    /* outputs
    [
      {
        "id": 1,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
      }
    ]
    */

    x = (x).Concat<JToken>(x) as JToken;
    Debug.WriteLine(x); // null
};
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you please show how you use the `Concat` method by providing your code +  sample data?

Comment: @GameScripting well the code is right here in question, specifically the line `x = (x).Concat<JToken>(x) as JToken`. UPD: can you see the code block I've provided?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, you're absolutly right.

Comment: I don't know Json.Net, but `concat` is usually for joining two strings.  I would expect a `merge` or `union` function would be more applicable.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
JToken.FromObject(x.Concat(x))
```

Answer (score 33):

**Use `JContainer.Merge()` with `MergeArrayHandling.Concat`.**

This is available starting with [Json.NET 6 Release 4](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection). So if your arrays are in a `JContainer` (e.g. a `JObject`), this is a simple and robust solution.

Example:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'Enabled': false,
  'Roles': [ 'User' ]
}");
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Enabled': true,
  'Roles': [ 'Operator', 'Admin' ]
}");

o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat });

string json = o1.ToString();
// {
//   "FirstName": "John",
//   "LastName": "Smith",
//   "Enabled": true,
//   "Roles": [
//     "User",
//     "Operator",
//     "Admin"
//   ]
// }
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed same, here's what I came up with

https://github.com/MrAntix/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/MergeExtensions.cs

```
public static void MergeInto(
    this JContainer left, JToken right, MergeOptions options)
{
    foreach (var rightChild in right.Children<JProperty>())
    {
        var rightChildProperty = rightChild;
        var leftPropertyValue = left.SelectToken(rightChildProperty.Name);

        if (leftPropertyValue == null)
        {
            // no matching property, just add 
            left.Add(rightChild);
        }
        else
        {
            var leftProperty = (JProperty) leftPropertyValue.Parent;

            var leftArray = leftPropertyValue as JArray;
            var rightArray = rightChildProperty.Value as JArray;
            if (leftArray != null && rightArray != null)
            {
                switch (options.ArrayHandling)
                {
                    case MergeOptionArrayHandling.Concat:

                        foreach (var rightValue in rightArray)
                        {
                            leftArray.Add(rightValue);
                        }

                        break;
                    case MergeOptionArrayHandling.Overwrite:

                        leftProperty.Value = rightChildProperty.Value;
                        break;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                var leftObject = leftPropertyValue as JObject;
                if (leftObject == null)
                {
                    // replace value
                    leftProperty.Value = rightChildProperty.Value;
                }

                else
                    // recurse object
                    MergeInto(leftObject, rightChildProperty.Value, options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `left.SelectToken(rightChildProperty.Name);` should be `left[rightChildProperty.Name];` ... at least in my case (4.0 R8)