# Merging two json files

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to merge two json files (i.e. multi.json and multiServer.json) into one json file.

I've tried quite a few approaches but I can't get it right. 
I thought that

```
   var x = multiSet + multiServerSet
```

would work, but it did not.

I also tried treating both variables as string but that messed up the format (my app. said something with wrong json format).

What would be the easiet approach?

```
        var multiSet = Resources.Load ("multi");
        var multiServerSet = Resources.Load ("multiServer");


        var mergedJson = ..... ?

        File.WriteAllText (filePath, mergedJson);
```

Both files follow the exact same format. I just want them merged into one file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121010/merge-two-json-net-arrays-by-concatenating-contained-elements)

Comment: Json lib has merge and add function. Does unity3d has this too?

Comment: You need to post what both json look like so that we can determine if they can be merged. @NeerajKumar C# is tagged but C# json does not work in Unity so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think so, @DragAndDrop.

Both json files are the following the exact same format. It's just that I have two files with the same format but different values.  I am sure it can be merged.

Comment: I can't find any reference of those function in miniJson I guess you will have to deserialise both into an object list then AddRange the list. And even clean duplicate the seialise it back.

Comment: @DragandDrop that sounds much more difficult than first anticipated ... but if there's no other way, I guess I have to attempt tthat.