# Merge JSON with same Item

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

Is there a way i can merge these JSON:

**JSON 1**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "date": "2018-08-25",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }]
}
```

**JSON 2**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "date": "2018-08-25",
        "id": 1,
        "age": 20,
        "address": "USA",
        "Weight": "256 kg"
    }]
}
```

**RESULT**

```
{
    "items": [{
        "date": "2018-08-25",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "age": 20,
        "address": "USA",
        "Weight": "256 kg"
    }]
}
```

Note that I want to merge JSON items which has the same id as the bearing.  Can this be achieved ? Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved. What have you tried ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121010/merge-two-json-net-arrays-by-concatenating-contained-elements)

Comment: @gogaz i have tried the merge of json.net but it keeps adding the latter to the tail end of the 11st json

Answer (score 3):

You can try to create some object for json1 and json2 data format.

```
public class Item1
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Object1
{
    public List<Item1> items { get; set; }
}
public class Item2
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public List<Item2> items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string Weight { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

and use `DeserializeObject` get object data from json string.

```
Object1 obj1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object1>(Json1);

Object2 obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object2>(Json2);
```

then use linq join to create the result list.

```
var resultList = (from o1 in obj1.items
join o2 in obj2.items on o1.id equals o2.id
select new Item()
{
    id = o1.id,
    date = o1.date,
    address = o2.address,
    age = o2.age,
     name = o1.name,
     Weight = o2.Weight
}).ToList();
```

final use `SerializeObject` transform `Result` to result json.

```
string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Result() { items = resultList });
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid create too many class, you can try to use `JObject.Parse`
linq `join` on `JToken` dictionary, so you didn't need to create the object class to carry JSON data.

```
var obj1 = JObject.Parse(Json1);
var obj2 = JObject.Parse(Json2);

var resultList = (from o1 in obj1["items"]
                  join o2 in obj2["items"] on o1["id"] equals o2["id"]
                  select new Item()
                  {
                      id = o1["id"].ToObject<int>(),
                      date = o1["date"].ToObject<string>(),
                      address = o2["address"].ToObject<string>(),
                      age = o2["age"].ToObject<int>(),
                      name = o1["name"].ToObject<string>(),
                      Weight = o2["Weight"].ToObject<string>()
                  }).ToList();
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Result() { items = resultList });

string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Result() { items = resultList });
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNyrs4)

**Result**

```
{
    "items":[
        {
        "date":"2018-08-25",
        "id":1,
        "name":"John",
        "age":20,
        "address":"USA",
        "Weight":"256 kg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: But this will be an inconvinience if i have several items. Is there a way I can do this dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? dynamically for create object or mapping or class?

Comment: yes. What if i have 100 items. Thatcw9uld be a lot of objects to create

Comment: with this, I still need to put in the 100 items under the select new Item()

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    "date": "2018-08-25",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
}
```

It can be deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, object>`