# Two files will not merge into one

Tags: c#, json, merge

I am trying to merge two files but they will not merge. I step through my code, the code I use to merge the files is below, each line runs but I do not get file 2 merged into file 1. The files are:

File = 1.json

```
{
  "count": 4,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "consumption": 0.004,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T07:00:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T07:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
      "consumption": 0.007,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T07:30:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T08:00:00+01:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

File = 2.json

```
{
  "count": 4,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "consumption": 0.007,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T08:00:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T08:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
      "consumption": 0.005,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T08:30:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T09:00:00+01:00"
   }
  ]
}
```

I am expecting to get 1.json as the resultant merged file as below

```
{
  "count": 4,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
    {
      "consumption": 0.004,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T07:00:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T07:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
      "consumption": 0.007,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T07:30:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T08:00:00+01:00"
    },
    {
      "consumption": 0.007,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T08:00:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T08:30:00+01:00"
    },
    {
      "consumption": 0.005,
      "interval_start": "2023-07-01T08:30:00+01:00",
      "interval_end": "2023-07-01T09:00:00+01:00"
   }
  ]
}
```

The piece of code I use to merge the two files is

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(Utilities.LoadJson(myPath)); //myPath = 1.json 
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(Utilities.LoadJson(path));    //path = 2.json

o1.Merge(o2);

//I also tried this line below instead of the line above but seems to result in the same
// o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings { MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat });
```

The function LoadJson() reads the file into a string as I believe the JOject needs to be parsed from a string

```
public static string LoadJson(string myFile)
{
      using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(myFile))
      {
           return r.ReadToEnd();
      }
 }
```

How can I get this to work the way I need it to work?

Comment: Shouldn't `"count"` be `2` in each of `1.json` and `2.json` (while remaining `4` in the combined file)?

Comment: Consider creating two classes, one that represents the _header_ (count, next, previous and a collection of results), and one that represents an individual result. Deserialize each file into a separate object. Then merge the results into a third one and serialize it back out

Comment: Use `JContainer.Merge()` with `MergeArrayHandling.Concat` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27502360/3744182) to [Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14121010/3744182) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756929/3744182) to [Merge two JTokens into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37756656/3744182).  In fact your question looks like a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @Flydog57: Unfortunately the API sends me the total number of items each time e.g. 4. I have to read how many I have got to know I need to make another call or not. The API is not mine so I have to work with what I get from it. You are right and your method would be better if I had the number in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add items to JArray

```
    o1["count"] = ((JArray)o1["results"]).Count
                     + ((JArray)o2["results"]).Count;

    foreach (JObject  o in o2["results"])
         ((JArray)o1["results"]).Add(o);
    
    string json = o1.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to teach me something I did not know. This is exactly what I needed.