# Union two JObjects with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

What I'm looking to do is union two JObjects with the JSON.net library.
An example would be

```
JObject j = JObject.Parse("{'test':1,'blah':2}");
JObject b = JObject.Parse("{'test':2}");
```

Would join to form the JSON Object equivalent to

```
{'test':2, 'blah':2}
```

Essentially the same operation as [jQuery's extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) but in JSON.net.
I can't seem to find a simple way to do this.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4002550/1342180

Comment: It does what is required, suprised there isn't a default operation within json.net though.