# Different ways to add and print keys/values to a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I couldn't find a relevant thread on this topic, so I decided to ask a new question. I'm at my first steps in the `Dictionary` class in **C#**, and I have several basic questions. First off, what the difference between this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    dict[1] = "hello";
```

and this (if any):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    dict.Add(1, "hello");
```

My second question is: is there any way to add multiple entries (if I can call a pair of key and value that way) on the same line. Something like `int a, b, c;`, instead of `int a; int b; int c;`. Or is it only possible to add them on multiple lines:

```
dict.Add(1, "hello");
dict.Add(2, "hey");
```

My last question, concerning the output of a dictionary, is if there is a "better" way to print a dictionary, instead of doing it that way:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
```

I mean "better" in terms of faster to type and faster to execute. (I know that it also works with `var`, instead of `KeyValuePair<>`.

Comment: don't worry too much regarding typing. Visual Studio can select text "vertically" (by holding down SHIFT **and** ALT), which becomes handy in situations such as needing to type/edit many almost identical lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **1. What the difference between this: `dict[1] = "hello"` and this: `dict.Add(1, "hello")`?**

Yes, there is a difference between using `Add` and `[]` indexer property.

You can call `dict[1] = "hello";` as many times as you want, but you can call `dict.Add(1, "hello");` only once. Otherwise it will throw `ArgumentException` saying *An item with the same key has already been added.*

> **2. Is there any way to add multiple entries (if I can call a pair of key and value that way) on the same line.**

You can only add multiple items in one line using collection initialization syntax, when `Dictionary` is created:

```
Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

But, it will be transformed to `Add` method calls by compiler anyway :)

Read [How to: Initialize a Dictionary with a Collection Initializer (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

> **3. Is if there is a "better" way to print a dictionary, instead of doing it that way:**

There is a way to print dictionary using one line expression, but I don't think it's more readable and it will use `foreach` loop internally anyway, so wan't be faster either:

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dict.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Key, x.Value))));
```

Answer (score 2):

First two snippets are equivalent is the key is not present in the dictionary, as can be found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/9tee9ht2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value associated with the specified key. If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.

If the key is present [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will throw:

> In contrast, the Add method throws an exception if a value with the specified key already exists.

The second question is answered [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx):

```
Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

The last question is subjective, it can be made a bit simpler then your snippet though using `var`:

```
foreach (var entry in dictionary)
    Console.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

> First off, what the difference between this `dict[1] = "hello"` and `dict.Add(1, "hello")`

In practice, there's no major difference. `[]` is an indexer and in effect it just calls `Add()` internally. However, being an indexer it can replace the value when the key already exists in the dictionary.

> My second question is: is there any way to add multiple entries (if I can call a pair of key and value that way) on the same line

Yes, when creating a new instance, you can supply an initializer like this:

```
new Dictionary<int, string> { { 1, "hello" }, { 2, "world" } }
```

However, you should bear in mind that sometimes more lines of code are better readable than one line of code. Remember other developers reading your code (and yourself 2 weeks from now).

> My last question, concerning the output of a dictionary, is if there is a "better" way to print a dictionary. … I mean "better" in terms of faster to type and faster to execute. (I know that it also works with `var`, instead of `KeyValuePair<>`.

- Again, you shouldn't sacrifice readability over number of lines of code. Your code is good and there's no need to make it any “better”.
- A very important rule: [do not optimize prematurely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize), i.e. don't care of performance unless you *really have* a performance problem.
- `var` has no impact on performance at all.

Comment: `dict[1] = "Hello"` will overwrite an element with the same key in the dictionary, whereas using `Add` will throw an exception in that case. So, no, the two are not the same. (I did not downvote...)

Comment: Does the downvoter care to comment? We are here to help, providing a reasonably elaborate answer to a beginner, and not to downvote for some corner-case omissions or simplifications.

Comment: @elgonzo Which is exactly what I added to my answer just a few minutes ago.

Comment: @elgonzo So if you are the downvoter, feel free to fix your vote or please state what else's wrong.

Comment: @Ondreij, i did not downvote, so i can't take it away; sorry about that. I still gave an upvote for your answer, for what it's worth...

Answer (score 1):

> **Q: What the difference between this: dict[1] = "hello" and this: dict.Add(1, "hello")?**

The logic behind Add and dict[something] is the same.

If you'll look at the Dictionary class source, you can see it uses the same Insert method for adding entries:

```
    public TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            // skipped
        }
        set {
            Insert(key, value, false);
        }
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
        Insert(key, value, true);
    }
```

It works the same way, except you can call Add only once with the same key.

> **Q: Is if there is a "better" way to print a dictionary, instead of doing it that way**

You can use:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
        {
            { 1, "asd" },
            { 2, "zxc" },
            { 3, "qwe" }
        };
```

> **Q: Is there any way to add multiple entries (if I can call a pair of key and value that way) on the same line.**

You can use simplified syntax:

```
        foreach (var pair in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair);
        }
```

Output is:

```
[1, asd]
[2, zxc]
[3, qwe]
```

Comment: Huh? They're actually VERY different: `Add` creates and will add the same entry only once w/o error. Accessing an entry by index won't create an entry at all, but you could use it a thousand times in a row, if the entry already exists - it would override its value again and again.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, I mentioned that.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Accessing entry by index **will** create an entry with given key if it not exists.

Answer (score 0):

One key difference between `dict[1] = "hello";` and `dict.Add(1, "hello");` is that `dict.Add()` will throw an `ArgumentException` if an item with that key already exists, while the indexer will simply overwrite the existing item. I didn't think C# had this behavior until I just tried it myself.

Regarding your second question, see this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633/why-doesnt-dictionary-have-addrange) for more details. Once a dictionary is constructed, you can't add multiple items at once using built-in methods. The other answers provide you ways of constructing a dictionary with multiple items at once.

For the third question, you are doing it about as well/readable as it can be done; if you feel like you are going to be doing this frequently, you perhaps would like to create an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void PrintDictionary<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {
        foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

You could then simply call `dict.PrintDictionary()` and get your desired output.

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are.

Comment: Like with Ondreij's answer, i too don't understand the negative feedback. Anyway, my upvote for a correct answer ...