# How to add multiple values to Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary

What is the best way to add multiple values to a Dictionary if I don't want to call "`.Add()`" multiple times.

**Edit**: I want to fill it after initiation! there are already some values in the Dictionary!

So instead of

```
    myDictionary.Add("a", "b");
    myDictionary.Add("f", "v");
    myDictionary.Add("s", "d");
    myDictionary.Add("r", "m");
    ...
```

I want to do something like this

```
 myDictionary.Add(["a","b"], ["f","v"],["s","d"]);
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use curly braces for that, though this only works for initialization:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "b"},
    {"f", "v"},
    {"s", "d"},
    {"r", "m"}
};
```

This is called "collection initialization" and works for any `ICollection<T>` (see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx) for dictionaries or this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for any other collection type). In fact, it works for any object type that implements `IEnumerable` and contains an `Add` method:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add<T1, T2, T3>(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3) { }
    // ...
}

Foo foo = new Foo
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {2, 3, 4}
};
```

Basically this is just syntactic sugar for calling the `Add`-method repeatedly. After initialization there are a few ways to do this, one of them being calling the `Add`-methods manually:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"a", "b"},
        {"f", "v"}
    };

var anotherDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"s", "d"},
        {"r", "m"}
    };

// Merge anotherDictionary into myDictionary, which may throw
// (as usually) on duplicate keys
foreach (var keyValuePair in anotherDictionary)
{
    myDictionary.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

Or as extension method:

```
static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void Add<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> target, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("target");

        foreach (var keyValuePair in source)
        {
            target.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        }
    }
}

var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"a", "b"},
        {"f", "v"}
    };

myDictionary.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"s", "d"},
        {"r", "m"}
    });
```

Comment: No way to fill it after initiation?

Comment: Just another for/foreach loop in combination with `Add`. This is just syntactic sugar for the add methods. There is no such thing as `AddRange` for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as keys need to be hashed anyway.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't exactly a duplicate question, but what you probably want is for there to be a `Dictionary.AddRange()` method. And here is why that doesn't exist:

[Why doesn't Dictionary have AddRange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633/why-doesnt-dictionary-have-addrange)

> "Range doesn't really have any meaning to an associative container."

But it might be a good idea to write your own `.AddRange()` method to the Dictionary class. It would essentially be a loop of `.Add()` calls though.

Comment: What he probably wanted is `.AddMultiple()`, or `.AddMany()`, or whatever, i.e the "range" word, which implies integer indexes, is not what he wants.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it at initialization like all other answer show, or you can combine it with this trick:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> secondDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{ 
    {"1", "a"}, 
    {"2", "b"} 
};
myDictionary = myDictionary.Union(secondDictionary)
                           .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

You have to make sure there are no duplicate keys or you will get an exception (but this ist the same with the `Add` method).

Comment: `Union` will result in another `IEnumerable<T>` which is not a dictionary anymore. This may also contain duplicate keys, since `KeyValuePair<T>` does not implement equality/hashcode based on keys (say it created a dictionary).

Comment: Added `ToDictionary` and a remark for duplicate keys.

Answer (score 5):

Although the question has been answered, I was curious if it would be possible to apply collection initializer-like syntax to a dictionary that was already initialized *without* the creation/overhead of creating a second dictionary to merge and throw away.

You can use (abuse?) [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to add a range of values to an existing Dictionary *after* it's creation. How? By creating a helper class to do it:

```
public class AddRangeTo<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> WrappedDictionary;

    public AddRangeTo(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> wrappedDictionary)
    {
        this.WrappedDictionary = wrappedDictionary;
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        this.WrappedDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

With usage:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

new AddRangeTo<string, string>(myDictionary)
{
    {"a", "b"},
    {"f", "v"},
    {"s", "d"},
    {"r", "m"}
};
```

Notice this allows you to add entries to the dictionary using a similar syntax but to a dictionary that's already been initialized. The part that kind of sucks is the repeat of the `<string, string>` generics, but that will not be necessary come C# 6.0. <s>(EDIT: That is, in C# 6 it would look like `new AddRangeTo(myDictionary)`)</s> (EDIT: This feature was scrapped from C# 6)

That all being said, I don't really recommend doing this necessarily. This is *odd* syntax/usage with unexpected side effects and I think might be confusing to others when they come across it. But if you find you would actually use this a lot and make your *internal* code easier to use and maintain, then bonus!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    {"a", "aa"},
    {"b", "bb"},
    {"c", "cc"},
    {"d", "dd"}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done out of the main code path in a way that allows you to reduce the clutter where it is happening using extension methods.

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
  public static IDictionary<TKey,TValue> AddRange<TKey,TValue>(
               this IDictionary<TKey,TValue> source,
               params  KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>[] items)
  {
    foreach (var keyValuePair in items)
    {
      source.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
    }
    return source;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would have been an easy google search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx.
Anyways...here is the code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { 'a', 'b' },
    { 'c', 'd' },
    { 'e', 'f' }
};
```

Of course, you can also write a loop or something to iterate over your values and calling the .add() method each time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can on initialization:

```
new Dictionary<string, string> { {"a","b"}, {"f","v"},{"s","d"} }
```

This is called a collection initializer.
When you want to add multiple items to an already existing dictionary, you can write a method.

Answer (score -1):

I have the perfect example for this initialization. Let's say you want to convert roman to integer. You receive a string with the roman number and you need a way to map what each character means. In **c#** you would use a dictionary with the characters and their equivalent integer

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, int>{
        {'M',1000},
        {'D',500},
        {'C',100},
        {'L',50},
        {'X',10},
        {'V',5},
        {'I',1}
    };
```

Answer (score -2):

myDictionary = new Dictionary() { {"a", 2) }, { "b", 3 }, };