# Simplest way to add all content of Dictionary<T1, T2> to another Dictionary<T1, T2> (equal types for key & value)?

Tags: c#

Is there a simpler way to copy/add all content of `source` dictionary to `destination` `Dictionary<T1, T2>` object than using one of the two options in the sample below?

```
Dictionary<string, int> source = new Dictionary<string, int>(),
    destination = new Dictionary<string, int>();

source.Add("Developers", 1);
source.Add("just", 2);
source.Add("wanna have", 3);
source.Add("FUN!", 4);

// Option 1 (feels like a hack):
//
source.All(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, int> p)
{
    destination.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
    return true;
});

// Option 2:
//
foreach (string k in source.Keys)
{
    destination.Add(k, source[k]);
}
```

What I was looking for is something like `.ForEach()`.

Comment: Does Option 1 or 2 work?

Comment: You mean like `List.ForEach`? [Be careful what you wish for..](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: Option 2 is about as simple as you can get.  You have a loop condition, and one statement within the loop.  Don't go complicating it by trying to shoehorn `ForEach`, and don't pass a delegate to a query method (`All`) that has side-effects.

Comment: @DStanley: Yes, that is what I thought.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633) for some arguments for and against a `ForEach` method, and some extension methods that may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, int> destination = new Dictionary<string, int>(source);
```

If `destination` is already filled and you don't want to lose them as commented i'd use this:

```
foreach (var kv in source)
    if (!destination.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
        destination.Add(kv.Key, kv.Value);
```

Comment: What if there are already key/value pairs inside `destination` you don't want to loose?

Comment: Here's the constructor documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @RhinoDevel: that's a different question and both of your options won't work either in that case if there are duplicates.

Comment: I don't want to create a copy of `source`, I want to copy/add all content of `source` to `destination`.

Comment: @RhinoDevel: look at my second approach. This is the easiest and most efficient appraoch if you want to add all "new".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict1.Add("first", 1);
Dictionary<string, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dict2.Add("second", 2);

dict2 = dict2.Concat(dict1).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

This of course doesn't really 'add' it to the dictionary, but replaces it by a new one. You can use [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Throws exception on duplicate keys and isn't efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Best option is just using a foreach like in OP's question but this is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> source = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    Dictionary<string, int> destination = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    destination.Add("Apple", 1);
    destination.Add("Banana", 2);
    foreach (var item in destination)
    {
        source.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
    foreach (var item in destination)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key is {0} and value is {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }       
}
```