# why can't we use re-throw with the ternary operator?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, throw, c#-7.0

In C#7 we can write this:

```
var a = 1 < 2 ? "true" : throw new Exception();
```

why can't we to do rethrowing? For example:

```
try
{
    var er = 1/0;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var a = ex.InnerException == null ? ex.Message : throw;
}
```

As far as my understanding of standart using `try-catch-throw`, there is some «context» (*contains throwed exception*) in the `try-catch` block passed into `throw` as non-obviously argument. Isn't it?

---

The same question with the null-coalescing operator - `??`.

Comment: Because nobody raised it as an expected use case, and so it never found it's way into the specifications; and since `throw <something>;` and `throw;` are actually quite different beasts, making things work for one of them doesn't mean it will *automatically* work for the other? Every feature starts at -100 points.

Comment: Damien, that would be my guess too, but the question is probably unanswerable by anyone except the language designers.

Comment: For what its worth, I'm glad this doesn't work. Throwing with new or re-throwing from a ternary just seems like an unstructured code smell. Maybe I'm just old school. I mean hey, why not nest the ternary operators. `var a = x < 2 ? x < 0 ? throw new Exception() : true : throw new Exception();`

Comment: @Mixxiphoid See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730250/is-there-a-difference-between-throw-and-throw-ex)

Comment: *to those who do vote for closing this question, do you really think that it makes community better?* Well, er, yes actually. Nobody is saying you have a bad question (in fact you havde no downvotes!), but the problem is you're asking why a language design decision was taken and nobody except the people who did it can answer that. That makes the question off topic.

Comment: @DavidG here we are do make the knowledge base, aren't we? Anybody can give an answer and we can vote for closing any bad answer. As you've mentioned, my question is not bad. And I'm absolutely sure that it will be helpful for me and for the community

Comment: @anatol Having a good question doesn't mean that it belongs on this site. For example, I can ask *"Where is my nearest postoffice?"* which is a good question but clearly doesn't belong on here. The fact that the answer to this is purely opinion based apart from a tiny collection of MS employees makes it off topic.

Comment: @DavidG okay, then do I need to reconstruct the question? I'm mostly interested in the understanding the mechanism how is `throw` works in `try-catch` clause

Comment: I'm not sure you can. The only answer we can give to the question "*why can't we rethrow with a ternary operator?*" is really just "*because it's not in the C# spec*".

Comment: @DavidG I want to know how a feature does work, what should I to do then? go to employ into Microsoft?

Comment: Are you now asking how does the re-throw feature work?

Comment: @DavidG as well

Comment: @DavidG same, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633/why-doesnt-dictionary-have-addrange) and try to tell me again that this is offtopic

Comment: That's a question from 7 years ago when the site rules were very different. You can't compare them to now I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG ok, so you should vote for closing too, shouldn't you?

Comment: There's no point in doing that for an ancient question as it takes 5 people to close a question, and 5 people with that power won't look at it.

Comment: this is unconvincing

Comment: The general answer to your question is provided a long time ago by the following [Eric Lippert blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/22/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods/). For the concrete issue, see the following currently open Roslyn issues - [Unable to use re-throw in expression form #25294](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/25294) and [Proposal: Rethrow Expressions #1340](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1340)

Comment: It is not in the spec. That's it: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1789#issuecomment-413755366 and more precisely here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1789#issuecomment-413946118

Comment: @chriga thanks but the first is mine )

Comment: @DavidG I still disagree, take a look at the blog post **IvanStoev** has posted. and there you'll see a link to the same *opinion-based* question.

Comment: You're talking about a question that was posted on this site nearly a decade ago. The site has changed dramatically since then. Even if it hadn't, your argument is the same as saying "*it's OK to stab my friend in the face because someone else did it too*".

Comment: @DavidG okay, here so many contradictions on this site that I've got in dissonance. those new rules are making *breaking changes*, aren't they?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "breaking"? And they're not really new rules either, they've been in place for probably 6 or 7 years now, maybe longer. Many old questions have been closed but many have been left there for historical purposes.