# How to AddRange in a HashTable?

Tags: c#, hashtable

```
HashTable list = new HashTable();
list.Add(1,"green");
list.Add(2,"blue");
list.Add(3,"red");
```

How to add these items like addrange in a HashTable?

Comment: there is no add range for this...

Comment: There isn't a method that does this. Although nothing is stopping you from maybe using an extension...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ perfect! Thanks!

Comment: FYI - know that you could also initialize the `Hashtable` like this - https://dotnetfiddle.net/rgKKjC

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why doesn't Dictionary have AddRange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050633/why-doesnt-dictionary-have-addrange)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is no `AddRange` for a `HashTable`, you *could* create an extension to at least mimic the `AddRange` behaviour. This is a quick answer to hopefully get you going, by no means this isn't the best implementation as there are other alternatives.

Here's an example extension -

```
 public static void AddRange<T, K>(this Hashtable hash, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T,K>> ikv)
 {
     foreach(KeyValuePair<T, K> kvp in ikv)
     {
        if (!hash.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        {
           hash.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);                    
        }                
     }
 }
```

Here's one way you can use it -

```
Hashtable list = new Hashtable();
list.AddRange(new[] { new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1,"green"), new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2,"blue"), new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3,"red") });
```

Again, this was a quick example to help you out, hopefully it's enough to get you going.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Hashtable list = new Hashtable
    {
        {1, "green"}, {2, "blue"}, {3, "red"}
    };

    // ICollection for keys 
    ICollection collection = list.Keys;

    // Write all
    foreach (var myList in collection)
        Console.WriteLine(myList + " - " + list[myList]);
```