# Combine multiple dictionaries into a single dictionary

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

dictionary 1

> "a", "1"
>   "b", "2"

dictionary 2

> "c", "3"
>   "d", "4"

dictionary 3

> "e", "5"
>   "f", "6"

Combined dictionary

> "a", "1"
>   "b", "2"
>   "c", "3"
>   "d", "4"
>   "e", "5"
>   "f", "6"

How do I combine the above 3 dictionaries into a single combined dictionary?

Comment: What should happen if you have keys with different values?

Comment: Sani..I created a class level private variable and then call another private method 1 dictionary at a time to add them to combined method. It does not look clean so I am asking for a better method here.

Comment: Can you show how your dictionaries are currently represented in the code?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var d3 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

var result = d1.Union(d2).Union(d3).ToDictionary (k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

**EDIT**
To ensure no duplicate keys use:

```
var result = d1.Concat(d2).Concat(d3).GroupBy(d => d.Key)
             .ToDictionary (d => d.Key, d => d.First().Value);
```

Comment: Note that `ToDictionary` will throw exception on duplicates

Comment: @dtb there wont be any duplicates when used with `union` as in my answer.

Comment: @Magnus: `Union` removes duplicates only if both key and value of the KeyValuePair are equal. If you have e.g. `var d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "a", 5 } }; var d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "a", 6 } };` then you get duplicate keys.

Comment: What would the solution be if you had an unknown number of Dictionaries you were trying to merge? Is there a way to take a List of dictionaries and merge them in the same way? thank you

Comment: @PaulW. You could do: `dictionaries.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)`

Answer (score 15):

Just loop through them:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var dict in dictionariesToCombine) {
    foreach (var item in dict) {
        result.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

(Assumes `dictionariesToCombine` is some `IEnumerable` of your dictionaries to combine, say, an array.)

Comment: thanks minitech, how do I createe IEnumerable of dictionaries?

Comment: `new Dictionary<string, string>[] { your, dictionaries, here }`

Comment: Note that `Add` will throw exception on duplicates

Comment: if (dict.ContainsKey(item.Key))
 dict[item.Key] = item.Value;
 else
 dict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

Comment: @abatishchev That doesn’t do the same thing on duplicates.

Comment: @Ry-: this would overwrite duplicates, indeed. But you're right, it depends on what behavior author wants.

Comment: This is much more computationally efficient than the accepted answer.