# Add to Dictionary Query Results of Multiple Linq Queries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I want to add result of 3 linq to a single dict.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();        
dict = ctx.tbl1.Where(a => a.Id == cid).ToDictionary(a => a.FieldName, a => a.LabelName);                   
dict = ctx.tbl2.Where(a => a.Id == cid).ToDictionary(a => a.FieldName, a => a.LabelName);   
dict = ctx.tbl3.Where(a => a.Id == cid).ToDictionary(a => a.FieldName, a => a.LabelName);                    
return dict;
```

The above code gives the last `dict` results. How to add to dictionary with every `linq` query result?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: dictionary does not contain AddRange method.. you need to add values one by one by checking whether key already exists or not..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine multiple dictionaries into a single dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559367/combine-multiple-dictionaries-into-a-single-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();        
foreach (var a in ctx.tbl1.Where(a => a.Id == cid)) dict.Add(a.FieldName, a.LabelName);
foreach (var a in ctx.tbl2.Where(a => a.Id == cid)) dict.Add(a.FieldName, a.LabelName);
foreach (var a in ctx.tbl3.Where(a => a.Id == cid)) dict.Add(a.FieldName, a.LabelName);
return dict;
```

A few things to consider, though:

This will throw if the same (case-sensitive) `a.FieldName` appears in more than one table or more than once in the same table for a given `a.Id`.

Does the underlying DB have constraints to prevent this from happening?  If probably ought to, unless the nature of the data is such that one `a.FieldName` could legitimately appear more than once for a given `a.Id`.  In that latter case, mapping them into a `ILookup` may be more appropriate.

If `a.FieldName` is not case-sensitive, create the dictionary with a case-insensitive string comparer.

If uniqueness of `a.Id,a.FieldName` applies across the aggregate of the 3 tables, would it make more sense for them to be replaced with a single table?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create your IEnumerable and then at the end convert it to Dictionary.

Provided your model is as below,

```
public class DummyModel
{
    private const decimal MinValue = 0m;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string LabelName { get; set; }

    //[DecimalValidatorAttrubute(precision: 2, maxdigits: 2, minValue: decimal.MinValue, maxValue: 99.99m)]
    //public decimal Decimal { get; set; }
}
```

Method below

```
private Dictionary<string, string> getDictionary()
    {
        var tbl1 = new List<DummyModel>() { new DummyModel() { Id = 1, FieldName = "Field1", LabelName = "Label1" }, new DummyModel() { FieldName = "Field2", LabelName = "Label2" } };
        var tbl2 = new List<DummyModel>() { new DummyModel() { Id = 1, FieldName = "Field3", LabelName = "Label3" }, new DummyModel() { FieldName = "Field4", LabelName = "Label4" } };
        var tbl3 = new List<DummyModel>() { new DummyModel() {Id = 1,FieldName = "Field5", LabelName = "Label5" }, new DummyModel() { FieldName = "Field6", LabelName = "Label6" } };
        const int cid = 1;

        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dict = tbl1.Where(a => a.Id == cid)
            .Concat(tbl2.Where(a => a.Id == cid))
            .Concat(tbl3.Where(a => a.Id == cid))
            .ToDictionary(a => a.FieldName, a => a.LabelName);
        return dict;
    }
```

Would help you to achive something like

```
[TestMethod]
    public void LinqDictionary()
    {
        var dict = getDictionary();
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FieldName {0}, LabelName {1} ", item.Key, item.Value);
        }

    }
```

Output

```
FieldName Field1, LabelName Label1
FieldName Field3, LabelName Label3 
FieldName Field5, LabelName Label5
```

Answer (score 0):

To add items to a dictionary from multiple queries,I use a bit more linq, directly add the first set to the dictionary, then use tolist and foreach to add subsequent items. I doubt performance is super, but in this case (adding controls) ts not likely to matter and TBH I doubt ToDictionary performs significantly faster anyway.

```
Dictionary<string, SomeObject> controlsChanged;
controlsChanged = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(c => c.Name).ToDictionary(k => k, v => new SomeObject());
this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().ToList().ForEach(c => controlsChanged.Add(c.Name, new SomeObject()));
```