# Union Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have two `Dictionary<Person,Boolean>`.
dict a contains :

```
Person A -> false
Person B -> true,
Person C -> false;
```

dict b contains :

```
Person A -> true;
Person D -> false;
```

I want to have an result, which contains all Persons one time, and set Boolean to ture, if a person contains a true in one of both lists.

How can i solve this with `dict.Union()` ?

Thanks Kooki

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Comment: _"all Persons one time"_ What makes your person distinct?

Comment: is equality determined by the hash key or by some custom comparison. If it's the hash is this the default implementation (which is semantically a ref comparison, so two identical objects  from a value perspective would still be different) or your own implementation?

Comment: Default equality is based on the reference and that seems quite adequate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you could use:

```
var result = first.Union(second)
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Key)                // Group by dictionary keys
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,           // Key for new dictionary
                                g => g.Any(p => p.Value)); // Any true values?
```

Comment: `Union` works only if `GetHashCode` and `Equals` was implemented correctly in `Person`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Well these are already in dictionaries, so either it works already, or the OP's just using reference equality.

Comment: Thanks, it works if GetHashCode() on Personclass working well... :-)