# C# appending Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, append, concatenation

how can i append Dictionary into another Dictionary ?

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> odict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        //Liste tous les Clients EMAIL (3)
        foreach (var TheClientID in TheClient.GetClient_Id(3))
        {
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> Temp = oEmail.VoirEML(TheClientID.Key);
             //odict = odict.Concat(Temp).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
            odict = odict.SelectMany(toto => Temp)
                     .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());
        }
```

i want to concat / append dictionary without double the entry.

Comment: What do you want to do about duplicate keys, if any?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do at the moment... could you give concrete examples?

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 8):

I once wrote an extension method for that because I needed the same. The last parameter decides what to do when duplicate keys are encountered.

`Skip` means source entry is kept.

`Overwrite` means "other" entry is used.

`Throw` will throw an Exception.

```
public enum DuplicateKeyHandling
{
    Skip,
    Overwrite,
    Throw
}

/// <summary>
/// Combines two dictionaries into one dictionary. The contents of the resulting dictionary depends on the <paramref name="duplicateKeyHandling"/> parameter.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the keys in the dictionaries</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the values in the dictionaries</typeparam>
/// <param name="this"></param>
/// <param name="other">The dictionary to combine this one with</param>
/// <param name="duplicateKeyHandling">Specifies how to react if the <paramref name="other"/> dictionary contains keys that are already in this dictionary</param>
/// <returns>A new dictionary containing the combined key-value-pairs of both source dictionaries</returns>
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Combine<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> @this, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> other, DuplicateKeyHandling duplicateKeyHandling = DuplicateKeyHandling.Skip)
{
    // EDIT: I added the "comparer" parameter so the resulting dictionary will
    // use the same comparer as the first source dictionary
    var result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(@this, @this.Comparer);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in other)
    {
        if (result.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        {
            if (duplicateKeyHandling == DuplicateKeyHandling.Overwrite)
            {
                result[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
            }

            if (duplicateKeyHandling == DuplicateKeyHandling.Throw)
            {
                throw new Exception("Duplicate key while combining dictionaries!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to use Linq is a mistake. It is easy to write and easy to read with a simple loop, and the extensions methods will not be any more efficient -- probably less efficient.

```
    Dictionary<string, DateTime> odict = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
    //Liste tous les Clients EMAIL (3)
    foreach(var TheClientID in TheClient.GetClient_Id(3)) {
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> Temp = oEmail.VoirEML(TheClientID.Key);
            //odict = odict.Concat(Temp).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
            foreach(var kvp in Temp){
                    odict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i try this :

```
odict = odict.Concat(Temp.Where(kvp => !odict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

and it works fine