# Dictionary Union to dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In my code I have the line

```
var d3 = d.Union(d2).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

This feels odd because its likely I'll do this a lot. There is no `.ToDictionary()`. How do I union a dictionary and keep it as a dictionary?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(1, "a"));
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(3, "b"));
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(9, "c"));
            var d = list.ToDictionary(
                s => s.Item1, 
                s => s.Item2);
            list.RemoveAt(2);
            var d2 = list.ToDictionary(
                s => s.Item1,
                s => s.Item2);
            d2[5] = "z";
            var d3 = d.Union(d2).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 18):

The problem with using the "straight" `Union` is that it does not interpret the dictionaries as dictionaries; it interprets dictionaries as `IEnumerable<KeyValyePair<K,V>>`. That is why you need that final `ToDictionary` step.

If your dictionaries do not have duplicate keys, this should work a little faster:

```
var d3 = d.Concat(d2).ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
```

Note that the `Union` method will break too if the two dictionaries contain the same key with different values. `Concat` will break if the dictionaries contain the same key even if it corresponds to the same value.

Comment: They do have the same keys but they have the same values. Also I was trying to get rid of the ToDictionary step. But Concat looks nice

Comment: I'm using Concat and it doesn't break with two dictionaries having the same key.