# How to merge 2 dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, collections, dictionary, merge

I have to aggregate two dictionaries.

Code:

```
private Dictionary <int, aor.PhysicalObject> agents;
private Dictionary <int, aor.PhysicalObject> objects;

agents = (from a in log
                   .InitialState
                   .Agents
                   .Agent 
         select a)
         .ToDictionary(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.id)
                       , d => d as aor.PhysicalObject);

objects = (from o in log
                     .InitialState
                     .Objects
                     .Object 
           select o)
           .ToDictionary(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.id)
                         , d => d as aor.PhysicalObject);
```

What I want now, is ONE dictionary containing all elements of the agents & objects dictionary.

You may think that there could be a problem with duplicate keys, but each key (id) is unique, so there will be no problem.

Would be very cool, if this task could be done via only one LINQ query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the keys are unique you could combine the two dictionaries as follows:

//Code

```
private Dictionary <int, aor.PhysicalObject> merger;

merger = Enumerable
         .Concat(  from a in log
                             .InitialState
                             .Agents
                             .Agent
                    select a
                 ,  from o in log
                              .InitialState
                              .Objects
                              .Object  
                     select o
                ).ToDictionary(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.id)
                                ,  d => d as aor.PhysicalObject);
```

Comment: Why would you write those LINQ queries instead of directly using `log.InitialState.Agents.Agent` and `log.InitialState.Objects.Object`?