# How can I union two dictionary with the same Key?

Tags: c#, linq, union

Dictionary 1:

```
Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>> PuntiCantieriCMS = new Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>();
```

Dictionary 2:

```
Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>> PuntiCantieri = new Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>();
```

I want Union those both; where the key is the same, they must union `IList<PuntoMappa>` for each key. Is it possible?

Tried:

```
PuntiCantieri = PuntiCantieri .Union(PuntiCantieriCMS ).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

but when 2 keys are similar, it trigger an exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Stop marking this as a duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp). The latter question doesn't care what happens in the case of key collisions, whereas this question clearly states that lists must be merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
Dictionary<string, List<PuntoMappa>> unioned = PuntiCantieriCMS
        .Concat(PuntiCantieri)
        .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.SelectMany(g => g.Value).ToList());
```

Note that i've changed the value from `IList<T>` to `List<T>`.

Comment: But it returns different type. In fact I can't do `PuntiCantieri = unioned;` after that Linq

Comment: @markzzz: If you need the `IList` cast it accordingly: `.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => (IList<PuntoMappa>)kv.SelectMany(g => g.Value).ToList());`

Comment: I think because I need `Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>`, not List :O

Comment: @markzzz: Yes, have you seen my _note_ ;-) My last comment shows how to cast it to `IList`.

Comment: Why changing `IList<T>` to `List<T>`?? It should work since `List<T>` is an `IList<T>`.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: No, i assume that's meant with [Covariance and Contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx). A `List<PuntoMappa>` is a `IList<PuntoMappa>` implicitely but a `Dictionary<string, List<PuntoMappa>>` is not a `Dictionary<string, IList<PuntoMappa>>`. The compiler doesn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach(var kvp in PuntiCantieri)
 {
      if(PuntiCantieriCMS.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
      {
         kvp.Value.AddRange(PuntiCantieriCMS[kvp.Key]);
      }

 }
```