# Concatenate two Dictionaries

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Given some Dictionaries

```
Dictionary<string, string> GroupNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> AddedGroupNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I am unable to merge them into one:

```
GroupNames = GroupNames.Concat(AddedGroupNames);
```

because "the type can't be implicitly converted". I believe (and my code proves me true) their type is the same - what am I overlooking?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that there won't be key collisions between `GroupNames` and `AddedGroupNames`?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I think you defined your `GroupNames` as `Dictionary<string,string>`, so you need to add `ToDictionary` like this:

```
GroupNames = GroupNames.Concat(AddedGroupNames)
                       .ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Note that 2 original dictionaries would have different keys, otherwise we need some rule to merge them correctly.

Comment: Great..this is far simpler solution compared to other answers given in the question marked above as original !

Comment: It's a good solution, but the only problem it has is about duplicate keys. If there is duplicate keys, an exception would be thrown.

Comment: If there are duplicate keys, use the following code 
`GroupNames = GroupNames.Concat(AddedGroupNames.Where( x=> !GroupNames.ContainsKey(x.Key))).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value)`