# Fastest way to equalize two dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary

I have two sorted dictionaries. The first one is just filled with NANs, the second one has some values.

I want to change NANs of the first one to values of the second one.

```
SortedDictionary<double, float> newlogdict = newlog.Samples;
SortedDictionary<double, float> oldlogdict = oldlog.Samples;

foreach (KeyValuePair<double, float> kvp in newlogdict)
{
    oldlogdict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
}
```

It works, but it is too slow, is there any faster way?

Comment: How fast do you want this?  You're going to have to touch every element in the dictionary anyway, so there's not much fat that can be removed here, if at all.

Comment: As fast as it can :)

Comment: Double seems like a weird key type for a Dictionary, what with rounding and all.  It strikes me odd that a type that should never really be checked for equality should be the key.  Now, you aren't checking the value, you are checking the hash, but it still isn't something I'd do.

Comment: Why don't you just pass `newlogdict` to the constructor of `oldlogdict` and see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't and it is still slow, then you need to change your design somehow so the slowness doesn't hinder the system.

Comment: Why do you need `SortedDictionary`? You could actually increase your performance by using `Dictionary` instead. Check this link out: https://www.dotnetperls.com/sorteddictionary

Comment: SortedDictionary is implemented as a tree. I would simply put the things into a Dictionary<double,float>. That should be significantly faster when it comes to merging. Do you need this sorted at all times?

Comment: Not a good idea to use floating points as a key because of imprecision as soon as you do some computation (i.e. (1.0 / 3.0) * 3.00 might give 0.999.. instead of 1)

Comment: What is the size of old and new dictionary before merge? Do you insert new keys after initial fill? Is NAN used for values, for keys or both (not clear in the question)? Do you really need 2 dictionaries and not one with both old and new value or directly update the single dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slow because your code increases the size oldlogdict (maybe it is doubling it).
If the

```
oldlogdict[kvp.Key]
```

in not found, then you are adding a new element with the following line

```
oldlogdict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
```

I tested your code with this sample data:

```
SortedDictionary<double, float> newlogdict = new SortedDictionary<double, float>();
SortedDictionary<double, float> oldlogdict = new SortedDictionary<double, float>();

float x1 = 3.5F;
double a = 3.3;

newlogdict.Add(double.NaN, x1);
oldlogdict.Add(a, x1);

foreach (KeyValuePair<double, float> kvp in newlogdict)
{
    oldlogdict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;      //if key is not found it will be added
}

Console.WriteLine(newlogdict.Count);
Console.WriteLine(oldlogdict.Count);
```

Please also note that in a `SortedDictionary` a `KeyNotFoundException` will only be thrown during a `Get` and not `Set` as documented on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2.item?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_SortedDictionary_2_Item__0_).

Answer (score -1):

This is concating or merging, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150527/concatenate-two-dictionaries/20150588)

seems there is no faster way, but there is shorter code