# How can I add additional Dictionary object

Tags: c#, linq

How Can I Add additional Dictionary Object below

```
var topLevel1 = resultRows.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

I want to add this within the LINQ line

```
  new Dictionary<string, object> { {"children", someDictionaryAgain}}
```

I want to append additional dictionary object after  the .ToDictionary()

something like

```
var topLevel1 = resultRows.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList()).Add(new Dictionary<string, object> {     {"somekey", "somevalueorobject"}}
```

Here is the expected output I wanted.

```
var toplevel = Dictionary <stirng, object> {
  {"Actual1", 0},
  {"Actual2", 0}
 }
```

After .ToDictionary() --> What code is best to use to achieve

```
    var toplevel = Dictionary <stirng, object> {
      {"Actual1", 0},
     {"Actual2", 0},
     {"AddedDynamically",0}
 }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: You want to make another new dictionary? How would that even work? I'm pretty sure I know what the answer is (that you can't) but would like to understand better what you are trying to do.

Comment: The value of topLevel1 should be two dictionaries?

Comment: I wanted to append additional Dictionary entry from the list dynamically

Comment: Nope just one, I'd like to add a custom dictionary value to the end of the ToDictionary Object created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToDictionary` outputs a `Dictionary`, so you can easily save the result into a variable and add to it. To ensure you're getting a `string` and `object` dictionary, though, you'll need to explicitly reference the types.

```
var topLevel1 = resultRows
    .GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,                                // This is fine since it returns a string
        g => { return g.ToList() as object; });    // Explicitlyreturn this as an object
topLevel1.Add("somekey", "somevalueorobject");
```

To expand nested collections, use `SelectMany` instead of `Select`

```
var topLevel1 = resultRows
    .GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(v => new { Key = g.Key, Value = v })) // This creates an anonymous type for use further into the query
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key,
        g => g.Value);
```

Comment: Looks close,  but can we do that in one line? i need lambda because the additional "somekey" will be children of the first dictionary.

Comment: The doing of this in one line for children of each dictionary? `.SelectMany` - I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: Nope I will take care of the children object "somevalueObject" I just  need to make your sample one LINQ syntax one liner. Not after the  fact of creating topLevel1. I'll wait for your update. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, for multiple reasons.

Primarily, because `ToDictionary` returns a new dictionary object (which you then assign). Calling `Add` on this returns `void`, so you can't do the assignment.

Basically, you have to leave your first line alone. To do the merge, you need to do a foreach. This part of the question has been discussed before at: [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Basically you end up with a loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in secondDictionary)
    topLevel1.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Note that the code above will break on a duplicate key.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

```
var topLevel1 = resultRows
.GroupBy(g => g["CustomerAccountType"])
.ToDictionary(
    g => g.Key,                                
    g => { return g.ToList() as object; }).Union(new Dictionary<string, object> {     {"somekey", "somevalueorobject"}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value);
```

Comment: this will not add duplicate entries since union means all shared and non-shared elements just once.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,object>>
```

then you have the dictionary you are looking for ...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void test()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> d1 = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Dictionary<string, int> d2 = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        d1.AddRange(d2);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Dictionary<K, V> AddRange<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> d1, Dictionary<K, V> d2)
    {
        foreach (var kv in d2)
        {
            d1[kv.Key] = kv.Value;
        }
        return d1;
    }
}
```

Using this extension function will:

- not fail upon duplicate key
- return the starting dictionary so you have a fluent interface

Comment: how will test method work while not providing the parameters to merge ?