# Impact of IEnumerable.ToList()

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering what goes on when calling `.ToList()` on an `IEnumerable` in C#.  Do the items actually get copied to completely new duplicated items on the heap or does the new List simply refer to the original items on the heap?

I'm wondering because someone told me it's expensive to call ToList, whereas if it's simply about assigning existing objects to a new list, that's a lightweight call.

I've written this fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/s7xIc2
Is simply checking the hashcode enough to know?

Comment: Granted, there are scenarios where there'll be problems.  I'm more concerned with the mechanics of whether a copy of the items are made.  Considerations about the size of the list is another discussion

Comment: Most of .Net code is publicly available - so http://referencesource.microsoft.com should be your first place to check what particular call does... And than ask clarifications on pieces you don't understand.

Comment: `.ToArray()` is slightly cheaper in terms of memory. It truncates itself before returning. `.ToList()` maintains a capacity buffer that often exceeds the length of the actual list.

Comment: I do agree with my colleague that's it's not worth calling ToList if you don't need to.  I just needed to be aware of whether the reference objects were "copied" to new instances or not.  Thanks to all for the comments ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IEnumerable` doesn't have to contain a list of anything.  It can (and often does) resolve each *current item* at the time it is requested.

On the other hand, an `IList` is a complete in-memory copy of all the items.

So the answer is... It depends.
What is backing your IEnumerable?  If its the file system then yes, calling .ToList can be quite expensive.  If its an in-memory list already, then no, calling .ToList would not be terribly expensive.

As an example, lets say you created an IEnumerable that generated and returned a random number each time .Next was called.   In this case calling .ToList on the IEnumerable would never return, and would eventually throw an Out Of Memory exception.

However, an IEnumerable of database objects has a finite bounds (usually :) ) and as long as all the data fits in memory, calling .ToList could be entirely appropriate.

Comment: In this specific scenario the data are POCO objects from an Entity Framework query

Comment: Calling .ToList on IQueryable is considered best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  It caught me off guard a little when the discussion occurred, because I was sure that as long as the items were reference type then only "references" would be made.  Just being questioned by a guy with a monumental amount more experience than myself had me second guessing

Comment: I'm using IQueryable for building the queries and ensuring deferred execution in our Repository assemblies, but the returned data ends up in the Business layer and dealing with IQueryables at that level would break our separation of responsibilities design.  Our business layer isn't supposed to know where the data comes from.  The Repository only returns IEnumerable of POCOs.  But where I need may need to deal with a List, then I considered ToList to be an decent option, but I was told at this point that I'd be making complete copies, which as it seems isn't the case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one version of ToList:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return new List<TSource>(source);
}
```

It creates a new list from the source, here is the constructor:

```
// Constructs a List, copying the contents of the given collection. The
// size and capacity of the new list will both be equal to the size of the
// given collection.
// 
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    if (collection==null)
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if( c != null) {
        int count = c.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            _items = _emptyArray;
        }
        else {
            _items = new T[count];
            c.CopyTo(_items, 0);
            _size = count;
        }
    }    
    else {                
        _size = 0;
        _items = _emptyArray;
        // This enumerable could be empty.  Let Add allocate a new array, if needed.
        // Note it will also go to _defaultCapacity first, not 1, then 2, etc.

        using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
            while(en.MoveNext()) {
                Add(en.Current);                                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It copies the items.

The code is from here: [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com)

Comment: I don't understand the down vote.  I didn't write the code!

Comment: Not my downvote by attribution of the code is *very* unclear.

Comment: Steve Wellens - Happens all the time on this site.  Try to help out and people get so picky as if they're making a difference.  So given I asked the question in the first place I'm going to say I find this code very helpful and I thank you very much.  It served two purposes - I can see what it's doing and I now know that MS have released the code to the public which I wasn't aware of.  This answer was of great service.  This is framework code so whether it's clear or not is of no concern to any commenters

Answer (score 3):

The `ToList()` create a new `List<T>` object that will contains reference to the original objects or a copy of the object if the type is a [Value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) (including [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct)).

For instance:

- A List of `int` would be full copy.
- A list of "Product" would be only reference to the product, not a full copy. If the original is modified, the product in the list would also be modified.

Comment: No that isn't true.   You can try it and see `List<int> L1 = new List<int>();
L1.Add(1);
L1.Add(1);
L1.Add(1);
List<int> L2 = L1.ToList();

L2[1] = 4;
`  After L2 is changed, L1 remains the same.

Comment: @SteveWellens, I think Zyo is correct in saying that a list of instances of "product" objects would be reference copies of those objects and would behave as he mentioned. Your example comment is using integers which are value types and thus would be full copies, similar to if they were structs.

Comment: @SteveWellens You example is correct, so is my explanation. int is [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), just like a struct and is always copy so the original is not updated.

Comment: @BateTech - Here is the example with object types: `List<string> L1 = new List<string>();
L1.Add("aaa");
L1.Add("aaa");
L1.Add("aaa");
List<string> L2 = L1.ToList();

L2[1] = "zzz";`  After the code runs, you have two different lists.  The objects are not shared.

Comment: @SteveWellens, String literals are not the case that was mentioned.  Try it with objects as members of the list.

Comment: @BateTech - You are correct, the objects are shared.