# Join multiple orderedDictionary in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ordereddictionary

How can I efficiently merge multiple `orderedDictionary`s?

In C#, I have checked online, but I could only see implementations for merging NamevaluePairs.

I am trying to join the below orderedDictionaries:

```
OrderedDictionary ticketToPickerMapForVerifiedTab = new OrderedDictionary();
OrderedDictionary ticketToPickerMapForHVTab = new OrderedDictionary();
OrderedDictionary ticketToPickerMapForKPTab = new OrderedDictionary();
```

The keys in those dictionaries are unique

I need the resultant collection to still be an OrderedDictionary object.

Please note that my question is different from the one asked here: *[Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)*

As that one demonstrated a case for Keyvaluepair<TKey,TValue>, while mine refers to using OrderedDictionary, because of the special functionality of OrderedDictionary consumed elsewhere in my code.

Comment: because without just call ticketToPickerMapForVerifiedTab.ToList();           AddRange(ticketToPickerMapForHVTab.ToList()) And the call toDictionary again

Comment: @AlexKrupka i do not understand your suggestion, could you be more elaborate there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Edwin try to change your code to use `SortedDictionary<K,V>` instead of `OrderedDictionary`, then you can use many Linq tricks easily...

Comment: @Eser , sorry i can't change that, i am using the index functionality of orderedDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to merge them. See the code below:

```
var dictionariesMerged = ticketToPickerMapForVerifiedTab.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Union(ticketToPickerMapForHVTab.Cast<DictionaryEntry>())
    .Union(ticketToPickerMapForKPTab.Cast<DictionaryEntry>());

var dictionary = new OrderedDictionary();

foreach (DictionaryEntry tuple in dictionariesMerged)
    dictionary.Add(tuple.Key, tuple.Value);
```

Comment: @Edwin do you want to join them or merge? 
Because if you want to join, you will have 3 values to same key.

Comment: i want to merge them , i am going to edit the question now

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below 'MergeDictionaries' method will merge the contents of the given dictionaries. This does not handle the case where one key exists in multiple dictionaries.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{

    private OrderedDictionary MergeDictionaries(params OrderedDictionary[] dictionaries)
    {
        var merged = new OrderedDictionary();
        foreach (var dictionary in dictionaries)
        {
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in dictionary)
            {
                merged.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var d1 = new OrderedDictionary
        {
            {"x", "v1"},
            {"b", "v2"},
        };
        var d2 = new OrderedDictionary
        {
            {"d", "v3" },
            {"c", "v4" }
        };
        var d3 = new OrderedDictionary
        {
            {"z", "v5" },
            {"y", "v6" }
        };

        var merged = MergeDictionaries(d1, d2, d3);

        var expected = new OrderedDictionary
        {
            {"b", "v2"},
            {"c", "v4" },
            {"d", "v3" },
            {"x", "v1"},
            {"y", "v6" },
            {"z", "v5" }
        };

        Assert.That(merged, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
    }
}
```