# How to join xml and datatable via linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, linq-to-dataset

I have a datatable which is holding two columns as 'Name' and 'Value'.

I have xml also which looks like below so I need to join datatable column with XML attribute then select XML Value if attribute value are present in datatable column.
 I have tried many possible ways but none of them helped .
   Please help me how to achieve this with help of linq!

Below is XML code

```
<Serverlist>
    <server name='Eric' value='9' />
    <server name='Donot' value='92' />
</Serverlist>
```

Below is code snippet which I have used

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("path");

var data = from dtt in dt.AsEnumerable()
           join xele in xelement.Descendants("server")
           on (string)dtt.Field<string>("Name") equals (string)xele.Attribute("name")
           select new { name =(String) xele.Attribute("name"), value=(string) xele.Attribute("value")};

foreach(var v in data) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

Comment: What is the current input? What is the current output? And what is the expected output?

Comment: current inputs are  attached xml and datatable with two column 'Name and Value and value are same as xml attribute value so according to that it should retrieve some value in data but current output is null.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I've tried it and it works. Maybe the problem is with the data in the data table. Can you show how you populate the data table?

Comment: For testing purpose I just used below simple code to create data table             DataTable dt=new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Value");
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = "Eric";
            dr["Value"] = 9;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["Name"] = "KI";
            dr1["Value"] = 9;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

Comment: Often these issue have to do with XML namespace.  Independently attempt to enumerate xml and datatable with code and see which is wrong.  You don't need the (String) in front of the dtt.Field<string> because the angle brackets are already doing the cast.

Comment: Your code is working and it is giving me `{ name = Eric, value = 9 }`

Comment: Yes Yacoub thanks for your quick response as now i converted to string hence it started working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to merge as opposed to join?

Convert them both to Dictionaries (the database list and the xml document). Then merge the two dictionaries together. Good examples are in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp). for example:

```
dictionaryFrom.ToList().ForEach(x => dictionaryTo.Add(x.Key, x.Value));
Simple and easy. According to this blog post it's even faster than most loops.
```