# Combining multiple dictionaries into one

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Let's assume I have two variables which both are of type `Dictionary<int, int>`.

```
Dictionary<int, int> d1 = new Dictionary<int, int> { ... };
Dictionary<int, int> d2 = new Dictionary<int, int> { ... };
```

Both dictionaries could potentionally contain the same keys.

I want them to combine into a single `Dictionary<int, int> combinedDictionary`.

What would be an elegant way to do this?

I've tried the following:

```
var combinedDictionary = d1.Concat(d2.Where(x => !d1.Keys.Contains(x.Key)));
```

But unfortunately, when trying to return this combined variable I get the following error:

> Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'.

Is it possible to safely cast it like this?

```
return (Dictionary<int, int>) combinedDictionary;
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp

Comment: Sure, there is lots of code out there to merge dictionaries.  Those examples do not explain why this approach isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.  You want to call ToDictionary to convert that into a Dictionary.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> combined = d1.Concat(d2.Where(x => !d1.Keys.Contains(x.Key)));
Dictionary<int, int> result = combined.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: @SeM The compiler didn't lie.  You can try it too.

Comment: Oopps, I didn't see this part in question `return (Dictionary<int, int>) combinedDictionary;`, sorry, move on.