# Merge two dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Knowing this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp), what is the way to join 2 (only) dictionaries (.Net 4.5)?

Duplicates not admitted, the first one wins (see example bellow).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        // combine both, keep first duplicate only 
        var result = d1.XXX?(d2); 

    }
}
```

say

`[<1,'a'>, <2, 'b'>]` + `[<3,'c'>, <1, 'x'>]` = > `[<1,'a'>, <2, 'b'>, <3,'c'>]`

Comment: If those were two Database tables with similar key values, I would use a join. I guess linq has a join equivalent too?

Comment: You already linked to an answer that seems to meet your needs. What about that answer does not work for you?

Comment: @DStanley there are a collection of dictionaries. But I have only two. should I create a collection only for that?

Comment: Why havent you at least provided a meaningful example?

Comment: @Serge you could - just use `var dicts = new [] {d1, d2}`.  A join might work too, but they are much more complicated in method syntax. There's not a simple built-in function that will do it.

Comment: `[<1,'a'>, <2, 'b'>] + [<3,'c'>, <1, 'x'>] = > [<1,'a'>, <2, 'b'>, <3,'c'>]`

Comment: @DStanley, I obtain an array, not a dictionary in your suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp)

Comment: even if specifying the version of .Net, I don't see how this question is any different from the one you linked to

Comment: @johnny5, please read carefully my comments above

Comment: I read your comments, but I would argue that the complexity between the two are trivial. In both causes you will be operating on an IEnumerable before merging into one, the only difference is that this provides more limitations than the prior answers

Comment: @johnny5, when two, I have any IEnumerable anywhere. this is why my question. Incdrebible how you insist to make a duplicate from a question I strarted with, so didn't find an answer there.

Comment: @Serge  my point is that there is no benefit to creating this limitation.  The answers from the original question will merge the dictionaries.  So using a simple wrapper to call the original answer will work. I don’t think you’re confused on how to build a wrapper to call the original answer, if that’s the case the question should be rephrased.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of wrapper I should create, once again I have no *one* array of *two* elements, I have just **two separate** elements. there is difference when you operate one single array, vs when you operate two entities..., say c = a+b is one thing, but the approach is different when you have `int []` and like to build a summ of elements. usually the second is a little bit more complex, the fist approach is easier, but *totally different*.

Comment: compare `c = a + b` vs `c = myArr.Sum()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You merge them like this:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>() { [1] = "one" };
var d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>() { [1] = "un", [2] = "deux" };

var merged = d1.Concat(d2)
    .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.First());
```

Comment: thanks, remark the .NET version ) But I see the idea! ;)

Comment: Should be available: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.5

Comment: I mean your dictionary initialization, that appeared with C# 6 ;)

Comment: Oh. Indeed, it was not supported.

Comment: Although `ToLookup` is fine it's little bit more expensive than `GroupBy` because it creates another collection in memory before creating the final `Dictionary`. I'd use it only if the lookup is my desired collection.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `Concat`, `GroupBy` and `First`:

```
var result = d1.Concat(d2)
               .GroupBy(kv => kv.Key)
               .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Value);
```

Comment: duplicates are not possible, as I say to keep fist value only (see the OP example), thank you

Comment: I see, but you started the answer with a supposition that is not admitted in the OP. ) thanks

Comment: the only difference from the other question is that I have exactly two, and not an array of dictionaries. I just wouldn't create an array of two dictionaries it seems unatural to me...