# Merging two dictionaries in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 dictionaries: `d1<string, Datetime?>` and `d2<string, Datetime?>` with contents as below:

```
d1["str1"] = 1/1/2011
d1["str2"] = 2/3/2014
d1["str3"] = 3/4/2022

d1["str2"] = 3/6/2019
d1["str3"] = 4/4/2023
d1["str4"] = 5/6/2027
```

I want to merge these dictionaries in one dictionary. But, while merging, if the key is common, it should take the latest date.

Below are the LINQ queries which are creating dictionaries d1 and d2:

```
var d1 = dbContext.table1.GroupBy(x => x.str1)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Distinct()
        .Select(r => r.Opened).Max());
        
var d2 = dbContext.table1.GroupBy(x => x.str1)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Distinct()
        .Select(r => r.Opened).Max());
```

I tried this query below but it gives null result:

```
var x = dbContext.table1.GroupBy(x => x.str1)
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Distinct()
            .Select(r => r.Opened).Max()).Union(dbContext.table2.GroupBy(x => x.str1)
            .ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Distinct()
            .Select(r => r.Opened).Max())).ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

I tried the query below too but its not considering the latest date if the key is common:

```
 var y = d1.Concat(d2.Where(x => !d1.Keys.Contains(x.Key)))
            .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);
```

How do I merge these 2 dictionaries to get the latest opened date if the key is common?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/294145/1714342

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/merging-dictionaries-in-c-sharp). Have a look at some of the answers as they provide guidance on how to deal with key clashes and even have generic extension methods that so that you can specify the merge behavior as described on your question.

Comment: @KamilBudziewski: The condition to merge is different than I need in the link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way,

```
    var d1 = new Dictionary<string, DateTime?>
    {
        {"str1", new DateTime(2011, 1, 1)},
        {"str2", new DateTime(2014, 2, 3)},
        {"str3", new DateTime(2022, 3, 4)}
    };

    var d2 = new Dictionary<string, DateTime?>
    {
        {"str2", new DateTime(2019, 3, 6)},
        {"str3", new DateTime(2023, 4, 4)},
        {"str4", new DateTime(2027, 5, 6)}
    };

        // Merge dictionaries and get the latest date for common keys
   var mergedDictionary = d1
       .Concat(d2)
       .GroupBy(pair => pair.Key)
       .ToDictionary(
           group => group.Key,
           group => group.Max(pair => pair.Value)
           //group => group.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).First().Value
       );

   // Display the merged dictionary
   Console.WriteLine("Merged Dictionary:");
```

Comment: `group.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).First().Value` => `group.Max(pair => pair.Value)` ?

Comment: Thanks all for the help. It resolved my issue.